# MySQL View: Order By then Group By (with a join thrown in for luck)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables (in mysql) `Book` and `BookPrice`, *BookPrice* stores the prices (over time) for the Books.

I would like a view that displays the Book data and its current price.

Table Stucture is:

**Book**

```
    BookId PK Int AI,
    BookTitle varchar(255)
```

**BookPrice**

```
    Id PK Int AI
    BookId Int (FK to Book)
    Price decimal(8,2)
    LastModified datetime
```

***Sample data***

**Book**

```
    1, Harry Potter
    2, LOTR
    3, Game of Thrones
    4, 50 Shades of Gray
```

**BookPrice**

```
    1, 1, 5.00, 2012-01-01 00:00:00
    2, 2, 10.00, 2012-01-01 00:00:00
    3, 3, 7.00, 2012-01-01 00:00:00
    4, 4, 0.99, 2012-01-01 00:00:00
    5, 1, 8.00, 2012-02-01 00:00:00
    6, 2, 9.00, 2012-02-01 00:00:00
```

With this data the view should display:

```
    BookId, Title, Price, PriceLastModified
    1, Harry Potter, 8.00, 2012-02-01 00:00:00
    2, LOTR, 9.00, 2012-02-01 00:00:00
    3, Game of Thrones, 7.00, 2012-01-01 00:00:00
    4, 50 Shades of Gray, 0.99,, 2012-01-01 00:00:00
```

I have tried (many variations) of the following:

```
SELECT `Book`.`Id`, `Book`.`Title`, `BookPrice`.`Price`, `BookPrice`.`LastModified`
FROM `Book` 
LEFT JOIN `BookPrice` ON `BookPrice`.`BookId` = `Book`.`Id`
GROUP BY `Book`.`Id`
ORDER BY `BookPrice`.`LastModified` DESC
```

However this appears to Group then Order, meaning it Groups, selecting the first price for each book (not the latest) 
so I get:

```
1, Harry Potter, 5.00, 2012-01-02 00:00:00
```

instead of the correct

```
1, Harry Potter, 8.00, 2012-02-01 00:00:00
```

and the same for LOTR

I managed to get this working using a sub-query instead of a join (don't know how good this is performance wise) but then can't create a view from that statement as views can't have sub-queries in the select statement.

Is there a way round this? or do I have to create an 'un grouped' view then a second view to group the first one?

I'm aware this is similar to questions asked before on SO and have looked at many other questions but couldn't find one the same (or deals with views)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the maximum `lastModifed` in a subquery and later join it again to your original query.

```
SELECT  a.*,b.*
FROM    book a
        INNER JOIN bookPrice b
            on a.bookid = b.bookid
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT bookID, MAX(lastModified) maxLast
            FROM bookPrice
            GROUP BY bookID
        ) c
            ON  b.bookid = c.bookid and
                b.lastmodified = c.maxlast
ORDER BY a.bookID
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5dd25/1)

**UPDATE 1**

You didn't mentioned that you will create a `View` from this query. And basically,`VIEW`s cannot contained subquery on it. The best way to do is to create a `VIEW` of he subquery

```
CREATE VIEW LastModifiedList
AS
SELECT bookID, MAX(lastModified) maxLast
FROM bookPrice
GROUP BY bookID
```

and joined this view to create another view.

```
CREATE View BookLatestPriceList
AS
SELECT  a.*,b.*
FROM    book a
        INNER JOIN bookPrice b
            on a.bookid = b.bookid
        INNER JOIN LastModifiedList c  -- <== view of the subquery
            ON b.bookid = c.bookid and
                b.lastmodified = c.maxlast
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d7d2/1)

Comment: Works, except when I try to create it as a view I get '#1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause'

Comment: @mattumotu Oh, yes you can't create subquery in a view. All you need to do is to create a `View` of the subquery and replace the current query's subquery to the view you created.

Comment: @mattumotu [Click this Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d7d2/1) to see how it works.